# Check if a lambda is noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, noexcept

I'm trying to check if a lambda is `noexcept` or not

but it looks like `noexcept(lambda)` doesn't do what I think it should.

```
auto lambda = [&](Widget& w){
    w.build();
};

auto isNoexcept = noexcept(lambda) ? "yes" : "no";
std::cout << "IsNoexcept: "  << isNoexcept << std::endl;
```

This prints "IsNoexcept: yes" even through the lambda is not marked `noexcept`.

What am I doing wrong here?

https://godbolt.org/z/EPfExoEad

Comment: Do you want a runtime check?

Comment: no. Just a compile time check so the function template is instantiated properly

Comment: Good, I just upvoted the answer you got!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda needs to be called, e.g.

```
auto isNoexcept = noexcept(lambda(std::declval<Widget&>())) ? "yes" : "no";
```

[`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) is used to check the expression throws or not, while the expression `lambda`, the lambda itself won't throw, until it's invoked (with specified arguments).

Comment: but noexcept(lambda()) doesn't compile since lambda takes a specific parameter. Can I check if the lambda is noexcept without passing in an actual value? Since I want the template function to be noexcept or not

Comment: @randomThought Not in general, because you can make a functor with an overloaded `operator()`, with only some of the overloads `noexcept`. If you're certain it's not overloaded and not templated, you could form a pointer-to-member to it, then use template specialization to see if it has noexcept in it.

Comment: @randomThought Arguments are required to call the lambda, you can construct them in-place like `lambda(std::declval<Widget&>())`.

Comment: lambda(std::declval<Widget&>()) was the missing piece. Thanks